# ggplot2 bold for part of a facet_wrap label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

A paper now in page proofs has been modified by the copy editor to have figure tags (e.g. 'A', 'B', ...) in **bold**, while the rest of the label is normal.  For example "**A** matches > 30", "**B** matches > 60".  I cannot figure out how to get facet_wrap() labeller to bold only part of the label string. I have not figured out how to get labeller=label_parsed to accept my bold string with >= in it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a bug in plotmath/as_labeller. The script below shows the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

f_vals = c(0.5, 0.8, 1.2, 1.5)
labs = c("A","B","C","D")

all_data=NULL

for (ix in 1:length(f_vals)) {
    dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20,mean=0,sd=f_vals[ix]),
        facet=f_vals[ix])

    all_data <- rbind(all_data,dat)
}
## this line fails with "sd:"
f_labs = sprintf("bold(%s)~~~the~sd ==~%.2f",labs, f_vals)
names(f_labs) = f_vals

facet_labeller = as_labeller(f_labs, label_parsed)

pA = ggplot(all_data, aes(x, x)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0)) +
  facet_wrap(~facet, labeller = facet_labeller)

pdf(file="test_bold3.pdf",width=8.0, height=6.0)
pA
```

As written, this code works as expected.  But if there is a colon (:) in the label string, e.g.

```
f_labs = sprintf("bold(%s)~~~the~sd: ==~%.2f",labs, f_vals)
```

The script fails with the message:

```
Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:1:19: unexpected '=='
1: bold(A)~~~the~sd: ==
                      ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... labeller -> default -> lapply -> FUN -> FUN -> parse
Execution halted
```

I was unable to find a combination of spaces and '~' that allowed a ':' in the label string.

Answer (score 0):

As you provided no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I don't know what's the issue with your code.

But here is a minimal reprex showing how you could achieve your desired result. Note the use of the `~` after `bold`

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1,
  y = 1,
  facet = c("bold(A)~matches > 30", "bold(B)~matches >= 60")
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~facet, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you show me an example using an as_labeller() object?  When I do the something very similar to what you have, (a named vector with the 4 strings I want with bold() and >=), and then use `facet_wrap(variable,labeller=my_labeller)`, I get the message: `Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:1:19: unexpected symbol
1: bold(A)~alignment length`

Comment: The best I could do would be to copy and paste the example from `?as_labeller`. (; Actually I have never used this in practice.

Comment: How did you learn to only put the '~' after bold(A)?

Comment: A bit of trial and error. Struggled with `?plotmath` myself in the beginning. But I learned that the result must be a valid expression and that most issues could be fixed by using either a `*` or a `~`.

Comment: Hm. I'm pretty sure it does. But without a minimal reproducible example of your approach it's hard to come up with a working solution. You could e.g. take my answer as starting point to create a minimal reprex suited to your real case.